# run Ms Fakes unit test on jenkins build server without installing visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, jenkins, microsoft-fakes

How to run Ms Fakes Unit test on Jenkins without installing Visual Studio?
Which DLLs are required from visual studio setup to run Fakes unit test on Jenkins Build Server?

We have tried to use VSTest.Console.exe for  ms fakes unit test, but on Jenkins it is giving error that "UnitTestIsolation instrumentation failed to initialize. Please restart Visual Studio"

Comment: Fakes require the Visual Studio test runner, and Visual Studio Premium or higher.

Comment: @Magus - Is it possible to run fakes unit test by copying only Visual Studio Test Runner related DLLs? Without installing Visual Studio.

Comment: @Nishant such setups are neither supported nor guaranteed to work

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install VS Ultimate and Premium to run Fakes